# How would I print out a map in descending order?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to iterate through the map from greatest to least and it has to print the top 10. I have to use map.h because its required so I can't use the normal map, I also cant use a vector. How would I just get the top 10 from the map from descending order?

Here is the [link](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/StanfordCPPLib/doc/Map-class.html#Constructor:Map) to the Stanford Map Library

```
#include <iostream>
#include "map.h"

using namespace std;

Map <string, int> wordFreq;
int counter = 0;
int max = 0;

for(string s : wordFreq)
  {
    if(wordFreq[s] > max)
    {
      counter++;
      max = wordFreq[s];
      cout << s << " : " << max << endl;

    }
    if(counter == 10)
    {
      exit(0);
    }
  }
```

I've been at this for a couple of hours so I think my logic is just bad.

Comment: How do you expect people to be able to answer this without knowing what the contents of `map.h` are?

Comment: yeah its the stanford map class

Comment: Just a guess but would it provide reverse-iterators `.rbegin()` and `.rend()` like many standard containers do?

Comment: I updated the post so theirs a link to the class. My professor said there is a way But I don't know what hes thinking.

Comment: what is the exact task you were given? I don't see how it can be done with that `Map` unless you use a different container (eg a stack) or wrap the key type. Are you allowed to use a `Map< my_custom_type, int>` ?

Comment: if the task is "get the top 10" then you do not need to iterate in reverse. You know the `size` and you can iterate in forward direction, thats all you need to get the last 10

Comment: Im allowed to use these.

#include <string> #include <cstring> #include "map.h" #include "glob.h"

Comment: Please elaborate on "the top 10". It seems that you have to consider the numerical order of the value (the ints in the map) not the alphabetical order of the keys (the strings). Is it correct? Can you provide a custom comparator to `Map`? I mean, you could just copy the values into a `Map<int, string>` and print the first (or last) ten elements...

Comment: @Andyrew -- If your goal is to get the top 10 frequency count, it is simple to see why your code would fail.  Assume that the first item in the map has a frequency count of 1000, and the rest have a frequency count less than that.  Your loop will see that 1000 is greater than max.  But on the next iterations of the loop, it will never record the other frequency counts, because they will all be less than max.

Comment: @Andyrew -- The simple solution would be, as stated, to copy the map to a `Map<int, string>`.  However assume that the map contains a lot of elements (let's say thousands of elements) -- copying an entire map to find the top 10 would not be an optimal way of doing this.  This is where using a min-heap would be appropriate, and possibly this is the answer the teacher is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need `top 10` value, you should use a minHeap with a size of 10 as you don't need to sort all the elements in the map.

Then sort the elements in minHeap before return if you need(maybe unsorted top10 values are excepted).

Answer (score 0):

This class has no way to iterate it other than a "visit all" function. So there's not going to be any good way to do it.

A simple hack is as follows:

1. Flip the sign of every `int` you use as a key before storing it in the map.
2. This will cause the map to visit its elements in reverse order.
3. Call `mapAll` with a visitor function that only prints the first ten times it's called. Don't forget to flip the sign of each key before printing it.

A less hacky way is to create `reversedInt` class that acts like an `int` but compares in reverse. That will avoid the need to flip signs and still let the map traverse in reverse.

It seems the provided `Map` class can accept a comparator in its constructor. So this might be the intended way to do this, I guess.

But the provided `Map` class is really just not suitable for this use.

Comment: note that OP is using the strings as keys. Maybe they actually want a `Map<int,string>` ...